# ¿Cómo visualizar una imagen desde otra web con CURL PHP?

Tags: php, imagen, curl

Estoy intentando extraer imágenes aleatorias desde otro sitio web, para visualizarlas desde mi web, lo he intentado, pero aún no logro descubrir mi error. ¿Podrían decirme cuál es el detalle? Muchas gracias

Esta es la URL desde donde intento hacerlo
https://bing.ioliu.cn/v1/rand?w=800&h=400

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
// Crear un nuevo recurso cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Configurar URL y otras opciones apropiadas
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://bing.ioliu.cn/v1/rand?w=800&h=400");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

// Capturar la URL y pasarla al navegador
curl_exec($ch);

// Cerrar el recurso cURL y liberar recursos del sistema
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: y si lo colocas directamente en el href??

Comment: esa url de la pregunta da un 404 diciendo que esa imagen no soporta esa resolucion... a ver si va a ser eso el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx esta filtrando por navegador y CURL no envia estos datos, debes agregar: CURLOPT_USERAGENT

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
// Crear un nuevo recurso cURL
$ch = curl_init();

// Configurar URL y otras opciones apropiadas
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://bing.ioliu.cn/v1/rand?w=800&h=400");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

//indicas al servidor que estas consutando que eres un navegador
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Safari/605.1.15");

// Capturar la URL y pasarla al navegador
curl_exec($ch);

// Cerrar el recurso cURL y liberar recursos del sistema
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: Ya pude extraer la imagen, pero la muestra en código,  ¿ cómo puedo convertirla a imagen?

Agregué un header para ver si podía codificar la imagen, pero sigue sin funcionar

`header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` es es el link al resultado [enlace]https://clientes.farmaciasmv.com/admin/curl